How to setup zsh with fzf history backsearch in tmux (I get zle errors)
I am using tmux with the zsh shell.
I try to setup fzf, and I do it like this (inside my zshrc):
eval "$(fzf --zsh)"

This works, as long as I am not in tmux. I can use Ctrl-R and get the fzf history search. But inside tmux this does nothing.
When I try to invoke the history back search manually, I get:
❯ fzf-history-widget
fzf-history-widget:zle:14: widgets can only be called when ZLE is active

A bit of googling suggests, that I need to load zle first, but also:
❯ zmodload zsh/zle

Does not work.
What is wrong? What can I do?
Edit:
As requested, here is the the output of bindkey | grep fzf:
❯ bindkey | grep fzf
"^I" fzf-completion
"^R" fzf-history-widget
"^T" fzf-file-widget
"^X." fzf-tab-debug
"^[c" fzf-cd-widget


Widgets are not meant to be invoked on the command line, they're meant to be bound to keys. What does bindkey | grep fzf return?

I added it to the question.

In which way does ^R not work?

Maybe enabling tracing for the function that backs that widget (functions -t fzf-history-widget) could help pin the problem.

I can't reproduce this, but the line in your .zshrc is not what the documentation says or what the installer sets up, and this could be the cause of your problem. Replace eval "$(fzf --zsh)" by source <(fzf --zsh) and try again.
